# Eliminar componente agregando clase con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una lista de elementos con diferentes id (simula ser una lista dinámica donde los datos viene de una base), y debo activar el botón de eliminar. Mi solución fue la siguiente:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).closest('section').addClass('btn-remove');
  });
```

Aqui el html

```
            <section class="row mt-3 mb-3 reg" id="1">
              <div class="col-1 text-center align-self-center" div>
                <p>01/06/19</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 text-center align-self-center">
                <p>Martin</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2 text-center align-self-center">
                <p>32654065</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-3 text-center align-self-center">
                <p>3794254368</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-1 text-center align-self-center">
                <p>01/07/96</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-6 text-center align-self-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="button">Eliminar</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-6 text-center align-self-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="accion"><a href="#">Atendido</a></button>
              </div>
            </section>
<section class="row mt-3 mb-3 reg" id="2">
              <div class="col-1 text-center align-self-center" div>
                <p>05/03/12</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 text-center align-self-center">
                <p>Damian</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2 text-center align-self-center">
                <p>21143056</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-3 text-center align-self-center">
                <p>3794213567</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-1 text-center align-self-center">
                <p>03/12/89</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-6 text-center align-self-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="button">Eliminar</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-6 text-center align-self-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="accion"><a href="#">Atendido</a></button>
              </div>
            </section>
```

Mi problema es que el botón solo reacciona con el primero, en este caso el paciente denominado "Martin".

Lo único que hace el botón es añadir la siguiente clase `display:none`

Comment: Primero, tienes `id` que se repiten, esto no es valido, es incorrecto. Si necesitar agruparlos de algún modo puedes usar una clase para los botones. El selector [$("#ID")](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) te devuelve el primer elemento y el único que debería de tener ese `id`. Ademas de esto no es lo mismo eliminar que ocultar, para eliminar un elemento puedes usar `.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

creo que esto ya lo han respondido muchas veces pero ahí va.

```
[id^='someId']
```

Dará las que empiecen con someId

```
[id$='someId']
```

Dará las que terminen con someId

```
[id*='someId']
```

Dará todos los Nodos que contengan someId